# Function for which $f(n) = 1$ is true only if n is prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, gamma-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions, natural-numbers

I was thinking a bit about the primes so I created a function which I checked in Wolfram.
It seems that this function is doing what i expected. It returns $1$ if value is prime otherwise it returns $0$.

Let:
$$f(n) = \lceil \frac{\Gamma(n)^2}{n} \rceil- \lfloor\frac{\Gamma(n)^2}{n} \rfloor$$
$$n \in \Bbb{N}$$
Then:
If $n$ is prime then $f(n) = 1$ else $f(n) = 0$.

Function in wolfram: [my function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DiscretePlot%5BCeiling%28Gamma%28n%29%5E2%2Fn%29%20-%20floor%28Gamma%28n%29%5E2%2Fn%29%2C%20%7Bn%2C%201%2C%20100%7D%5D).

---

I know that to truly say that this is true, there is needed a proof.

---

Can such function be useful in math or it is just a clever useless property ? 
Can we say anythink more about this function ?

Are there any other interesting functions that are strongly connected with prime numbers ? 
I know that there are :

- prmie counting function
- rieman zetta function
- [formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes)

Comment: A USEFUL formula for primes is not in sight. With USEFUL, I mean a formula that allows us to find any (and really any!) large yet undiscovered prime number. This is what mathematicians mean with "the primes are random". This is often misunderstood and people often get angry and counter that the primes are determined and therefore not random.

Comment: Actually this function allows to find all primes, but there is one catch. This function is hard to be calculated on computers, due to their limited precision.

Comment: Read Dudley's 1983 [Formulas for Primes](https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/formulas-for-primes).

Answer (score 2):

Well, $$\lceil x \rceil - \lfloor x \rfloor = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 \ \ x \in \mathbb{Z} \\
      1 \ \ x \notin \mathbb{Z}
\end{array} 
\right. $$

Note that $\frac{\Gamma(n)}{n}^2 = \frac{((n-1)!)^2}{n}$ is an integer $\iff$ $n$ is not a prime number.

Comment: Yes it is what's happens, but it don't work only for $n=4$. It'is why I am using $\Gamma(n)^2$.

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 That's not true... $\frac{\Gamma(4)}4=\frac32$

Comment: Indeed, now it is fixed.

Comment: With $2\Gamma(n)$ function won't work for $n=2$ which is prime.